# Array of hashmap output in json

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, hashmap

I wrote the below code which gives me the following output:

```
String jsonInString = "NORESPONSE";
List<Map<String , String>> detailsArray = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String entry = split[i];
    j++;

    String entrySplit[] = entry.split("\\:");
    details.put("PrimaryEmail", entrySplit[0]);
    details.put("DisplayName", entrySplit[1]);

    allEntries.put("Entry " + j , details);
    //detailsArray.add(i, details);
}

json.putAll(allEntries);
jsonInString = json.toJSONString();
logger.info(jsonInString);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Entry 2": {
    "DisplayName": "OICT-Focal Points All",
    "PrimaryEmail": "oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"
  },
  "Entry 3": {
    "DisplayName": "OICT-Focal Points All",
    "PrimaryEmail": "oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"
  },
  "Entry 1": {
    "DisplayName": "OICT-Focal Points All",
    "PrimaryEmail": "oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"
  }
}
```

But, I wanted an output of the below kind. What changes are required to my code? It will be great if any one can help me out. Thanks in advance

```
[{"DisplayName":"OICT-Focal Points All","PrimaryEmail":"oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"},{"DisplayName":"OICT-Focal Points All","PrimaryEmail":"oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"},{"DisplayName":"OICT-Focal Points All","PrimaryEmail":"oict-oict-globalvtc@un87.org"}]
```

Comment: Why don't you create the`JsonObject` within the loop and add them to `JsonArray` instead of hashmap?

Comment: Since JSONObject extends HashMap, it requires a key/value pair for each property. The best you are likely to do is to set a property like "entries" with the detailsArray as the value. (Of course, this will require uncommenting the detailsArray.add line). You would then call json.put("entries", detailsArray), and your output would be {"entries": [...]}. If you're not hooked on using JSONObject, you could use ObjectMapper from the Jackson library (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). I like @Pete's suggestion better!

Comment: Hi Pete, Can you share me a sample code

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Pete's comment, here is sample code (untested):

```
String jsonInString = "NORESPONSE";
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObj;

for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String entry = split[i];
    jsonObj = new JSONObject();

    String entrySplit[] = entry.split("\\:");
    jsonObj.put("PrimaryEmail", entrySplit[0]);
    jsonObj.put("DisplayName", entrySplit[1]);

    json.put(jsonObj);
}

jsonInString = json.toJSONString();
logger.info(jsonInString);
```